# Responsive tabs issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I've created this responsive tabs to accordion plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/plqTygiscmc2j9rB9bW0?p=preview - now using AngularJS.

The responsiveness happens as it should (like this: http://webtrendset.com/demo/easy-responsive-tabs/Index.html), however the tabs functionality isn't working which is the whole idea.

Before trying to integrate it with angular (using a directive) it worked just fine, but the idea is to use angularjs.

Just wondering what I've missed? Thank you.

Comment: The html content (divs, etc.) should be within the `body` tag. Did you get it working firstly with some dummy text, before attempting with the `todos`?

Comment: @AndyG: Thanks for the edit Andy, title makes much more sense now. I had it working prior to trying with angular if that's what you mean? Otherwise even without JSON data, and just using dummy text (after including angular), it just won't work. Updated plunker to include the opening `body` tag :) thanks

Comment: I got it working with some dummy `li`s and replacing the `p-tags` with `divs`, as per the instruction-page. So it is a problem with the `todos`, not the accordion.

Comment: @AndyG: Really? hmmm any chance you can show a working plunker so I can take a look? It's using angular still though right? As that's the whole idea.
Updated question so you know what I'm having the exact issue with.

Comment: I also removed the unnecessary comment delimiters form the script. As I say, I just used dummy text, getting rid of the `todo` stuff.

Comment: @AndyG: If I remove the `todo` stuff in html and replace with `li`'s and `p`'s accordingly, it still doesn't work?

Comment: @AndyG: So we don't have any miscommunication here, I'm trying to make that plugin integrate and work as a directive in Angular..

Comment: I don't use AngularJS, or Plunker, so someone else will need to help you further. Good luck.

Comment: Dave, could you post a plnkr of your working solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some technical problems with your directive, as well as an architectural one. Let's start with the easy part:

- You're using `Tabs={...}` but your directive is called `TabsDirective`. Plus, directives must have camel cased names. So your directive should be renamed as either `tabs` or `tabsDirective` (though it seems a little redundant to use 'directive" in a directive's name).
- You're using `<p>` tags inside the `resp-tabs-container` div, but according to Easy Responsive Tabs docs, you should use `<div>` tags instead.

Now to the big problem. When your directive is executed, the content of the `div` it is applied to hasn't been processed by Angular yet, so when the `link` function runs and it calls `$(element).easyResponsiveTabs(...)`, the element markup isn't fully rendered and the plugin simply doesn't work. And since the directive is applied to the div that wraps the content, it'll always be executed prior to the rendering of that content.

There's a hack you can use in order to make it work: delay the `easyResponsiveTabs` call a little bit so that Angular fully renders the div content. You can use the `$timeout` service to do that. It's not perfect, though: it may not work if the delay isn't long enough and you may see the original markup before it's converted by the EasyReponsiveTags plugin (the longer the delay, the longer the original markup is visible). This [fork of your Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iuQLyg1X1aGcd86k78yT?p=preview) illustrates that.

I think the correct way to handle this is to create a directive that controls how and when the tabs are rendered. If you're willing to do it, the example in the section "Creating components" in Angular's home page should get you started.

Comment: That works but yes, definitely agree with creating a directive controller. Will be doing that now! Thank you again! Upvoted and accepted.

Comment: Sorry Michael, that was intended for Dave... I've added the same comment to his original question. Was hoping to see it working because I couldn't get it to work.